# position undefined running Three.js component in React

Tags: reactjs, three.js

I am running a three.js component inside a React (Typescript) app, everything was working fine rendering my 3D object, until I started to add some more functionality with vertex colors and now I am getting an error "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'position')" at line 27:

```
const count = geometry.attributes.position.count;
```

Is there an issue I am facing here with scope or its implementation as a component?

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import * as THREE from "three";

class MyBox extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {

        let mouseX = 0;
        let mouseY = 0;
        let windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
        let windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;
        const radius = 1;

        const scene = new THREE.Scene();
        const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
        const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth / 2, window.innerHeight / 2);
        this.mount.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

        var geometry = new THREE.IcosahedronGeometry(radius, 1);
        const count = geometry.attributes.position.count;
        geometry.setAttribute('color', new THREE.BufferAttribute(new Float32Array(count * 3), 3));
        const color = new THREE.Color();
        const positions = geometry.attributes.position;
        const colors = geometry.attributes.color;

        for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {

            color.setHSL((positions.getY(i) / radius + 1) / 2, 1.0, 0.5);
            colors.setXYZ(i, color.r, color.g, color.b);
        }

        var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: 0x7e31eb, vertexColours: true, shininess: 100 });
        var cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
        scene.add(cube);

        var wiregeometry = new THREE.IcosahedronGeometry(radius + 0.01, 1);
        var wirematerial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xffffff, wireframe: true });
        var wirecube = new THREE.Mesh(wiregeometry, wirematerial);
        scene.add(wirecube);

        const light = new THREE.HemisphereLight(0xffffbb, 0x080820, 1);
        scene.add(light);
        camera.position.z = 2;

        document.addEventListener('mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove);

        function onDocumentMouseMove(event) {

            mouseX = (event.clientX - windowHalfX);
            mouseY = (event.clientY - windowHalfY);

        }

        var animate = function() {
            requestAnimationFrame(animate);
            wirecube.rotation.x += mouseY / 20000;
            wirecube.rotation.y += mouseX / 20000;
            wirecube.rotation.z += 0.00;
            cube.rotation.x += mouseY / 20000;
            cube.rotation.y += mouseX / 20000;
            cube.rotation.z += 0.00;
            renderer.render(scene, camera);
        };
        animate();

        renderer.render(scene, camera);


    }
    render() {
        return ( <
            div ref = { ref => (this.mount = ref) }
            />
        )
    }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root")
ReactDOM.render( < MyBox / > , rootElement);

export default MyBox;
```

Similarly, if I write

```
var position = geometry.getAttribute('position');
```

I get a "geometry.getAttribute is not a function" error, which seems odd because that code would usually work for me.

Comment: What version of Three.js do you use? It's [works](https://codesandbox.io/s/pure-three-js-react-16-integration-forked-9ljp3?file=/src/index.js) on latest version `0.132.2`

Comment: Thanks, this was the issue.  I was on 124 and upgrading has fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Users encountered problems when mixing ThreeJS version with incompatible plugins. Try using the files for everything from the same release.

Example of a user using incompatible versions: https://discourse.threejs.org/t/buffergeometry-setattribute-is-not-a-function-error/22856

Comment: my only import is import * as THREE from "three", so I am not using any other three plugins